# Change description language in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar api to insert the events in a calendar. Is there a google calendar api to change the description of the calendar event according to the one set by the user.

Please answer my query.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share with us what you have done so far (with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that we may look into your code and determine where you had issues? Also, have you tried the method [Events:Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update)? According to the article, the minimum requirement for updating an event description would be a request body with a `start`, `end`, and `description` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Events patch method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch) will allow you to update the description of an event

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDARID]/events/[EVENTID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "test"
}
```

Just remember with patch to only send the properties you want to edit don't send the ones you wish to remain the same.

Comment: Hey! Thank you, it works. I also want to change the language to Spanish from English. Is there any method to do so without using google translation api?

Comment: try updating locale  but as far as i know.  As far as i know its inserted and returned in what ever language it was inserted in.   they arent going to translate it directly for you.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will also improve your rep.